# UIWebView With PDF

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I'm displaying a PDF file using `UIWebView`, and I want to do 2 things:

1. I want to make the page fit the phone screen without the user has to double tap to do that
2. I want to remove the margin with gray shadow around the displayed PDF

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will help much, but I think your best option is to render the PDF to an image (of decent DPI) and show the image instead.  I do this for an app, but we do that server side using ImageMagick - don't know how you might do that in obj-c.  Also note that a mostly-text PDF will be much larger (filesize) when rasterized.

However, you might also try to embed the PDF in HTML page and load that HTML in the WebView - that may at least avoid the gray border/artboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale( webView.transform, 1.25, 1.25 );
```

Answer (score 1):

2 - Checking the *Scale Pages to Fit* box in IB sorted this for me

I would also like to know the answer to 1. 
I guess you want to know how to display the PDF in the same way as when opening as attachment in mail, where the navigation bar only appears on a tap and the status bar also disappears?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Quartz to do it, as explained here : http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

Answer (score -1):

Where has CGAFFineTransformScale been all my life?

Seriously, that is a big help. However, it worked better applying it to webView.scrollView.

Finally, is there a similar command to change the offset of the content as well as the scale?

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Please do not post questions as an answer. Thank you.