# PDF in UIWebView: Initial view to fill view

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that displays a PDF. By default it opens the PDF and scales it to fit the entire width in the view, but not the height. I want it to fill the view so that the height stretches down to the bottom.

I have tried using `contentModeScaleToFill`, `zoomToRect`, and any other thing that sounded like it might have any relevance.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? Maybe this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577663/how-to-fit-pdf-height-in-uiwebview-in-iphone-ipad?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [@Jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236415/jeff) suggestion and use [CGAffineTransformScale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) to rescale your pdf after it is loaded to fill the screen. Look at his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3600665/188675

And to answer your question, 1) **contentModeScaleToFill** is a *UIView Constant* so it won't help with anything in your case, because you're using a *UIWebView*. 2) Using *CFAffineTransformScale* is much more simple and straightforward than using **zoomToRect** because you don't have to mess with the *scrollView*.

Comment: Where has CGAFFineTransformScale been all my life?

Seriously, that is a big help. However, it worked better applying it to webView.scrollView.

Finally, is there a similar command to change the offset of the content as well as the scale?